# ItemRenderer images not show

Tags: android, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

I need some help with images on List. I have a List with ItemRenderer on second .mxml file. List must show a title and image from rss item, but my images on list don`t show :( What is wrong with my code?

This is HomeView.mxml code:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        xmlns:rssreader="services.rssreader.*"
        fontWeight="bold" title="Elektro-Vozila" viewActivate="getData()">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;
            protected function getData():void
            {
                getDataResult.token = rssreader.getData();
            }

            import mx.events.CollectionEvent;
            import valueObjects.Item;


            protected function fixEntityReferences(event:CollectionEvent):void
            {
                myList.labelFunction = replaceEntity;

                function replaceEntity(item:Item):String
                {
                    var p1:RegExp = /(&quot;)/ig; // perhaps add more here later
                    var thisString:String = item.title.replace(p1, "");
                    trace(thisString);
                    return thisString;

                }

            }

            protected function myList_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
            {

                var RSSItem:Object = myList.dataProvider.getItemAt(event.newIndex);
                navigator.pushView(DetailsView, RSSItem);
            }

        ]]>

    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:CallResponder id="getDataResult"/>
        <rssreader:Rssreader id="rssreader"/>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:navigationContent>
        <s:Image right="20" height="52" source="images/logo.png"/>
    </s:navigationContent>

    <s:List id="myList" width="100%" height="100%" change="myList_changeHandler(event)" fontSize="0"
            fontWeight="normal" itemRenderer="views.icon">

        <s:AsyncListView list="{getDataResult.lastResult}"
                         collectionChange="fixEntityReferences(event)"/>

    </s:List>
</s:View>

And this is code from icon.mxml:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer  xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                 xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                 autoDrawBackground="true">

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal" />
        <s:State name="selected" />
    </s:states>
    <s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%" gap="0">
        <s:HGroup width="100%" height="100%">
            <s:Image width="72" height="72" source="{data.rimage}"
                     scaleMode.normal="stretch"/>


            <s:VGroup width="100%" height="70" gap="0" paddingBottom="10" paddingLeft="10"
                      paddingRight="10" paddingTop="10"
                      height.normal="90" horizontalAlign.normal="justify">
                <s:Label text="{data.title}"
                         fontSize.normal="16" fontWeight.normal="normal"
                         verticalAlign.normal="justify"
                         styleName.selected="menuTitleText"/>

            </s:VGroup>
        </s:HGroup>
        <s:Line width="100%"><s:stroke><s:SolidColorStroke color="0x808080" weight="1" /></s:stroke></s:Line>
    </s:VGroup>


</s:ItemRenderer>
```

I try to use some rimage options include source="data.rimage", rimage, {data.rimage}... but not working :(

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        xmlns:rssreader="services.rssreader.*"
        title="{rtitle}" viewActivate="getDetails()">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            import valueObjects.Item;

            [Bindable] public var rimage:String;
            [Bindable] private var rtitle:String;
            [Bindable] private var rlink:String;
            [Bindable] private var rdesc:String;



            private function getDetails():void
            {

                var thisItem:Item = data as Item;

                rtitle = thisItem.title;
                rlink = thisItem.link;
                rdesc = thisItem.description;


                var descArr:Array = rdesc.split("src=");
                var resArr:Array = descArr[1].split(".jpg");
                var resArr2:Array = resArr[0].split("\"");
                rimage = resArr2[1] + ".jpg";

}


        ]]>

    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:CallResponder id="getDataResult"/>
        <rssreader:Rssreader id="rssreader"/>


    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:navigationContent>
        <s:Button label="Nazaj" click="navigator.popView()" />
    </s:navigationContent>
    <s:BorderContainer top="0" bottom="0" left="0" right="0"
                       backgroundColor="#FFFFFF">


        <s:Label left="20" right="20" top="42" height="61"
                 backgroundColor="#FFFFFF" color="#000000" fontSize="24"
                 paddingBottom="30" paddingLeft="5" paddingRight="5"
                 paddingTop="5" text="{rtitle}"/>


        <s:Label left="20" right="90" top="14" height="23" backgroundColor="#FEFDFD" color="#666666"
                 fontSize="18" fontStyle="italic" paddingBottom="5" paddingLeft="5" paddingRight="5"
                 paddingTop="5" text="Objavljeno: {rdate}"/>

        <s:BitmapImage y="110" left="20" right="20" smooth="true" smoothingQuality="high"
                       source="{rimage}" />

        <s:Label left="20" right="20" top="264" bottom="135" color="#666666"
                 backgroundColor="#FFFFFF" fontSize="18" paddingBottom="5"
                 paddingLeft="5" paddingRight="5" paddingTop="15"
                 text="{rdesc2}" maxDisplayedLines="10" />

        <s:Button left="50" right="50" bottom="22" label="Preberi celoten članek"
                  click="navigator.pushView(ClanekHTML, data.link)"/>







    </s:BorderContainer>

</s:View>
```

Ou, here is code from DetailsView.mxml where rimage is located:

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I think from how you describe it the rImage has the wrong path.  Remember that the paths resolved at run-time if given as a relative path will be relative to the swf/apk execution location.  If you have your images in a package where the code is located then it will end up in that package structure when you build, however the MXML will all be compiled into a swf that is at the root of the output folder.  I recommend creating a separate package, call it resources, include it in the flex build path as a source folder, make an images folder in there and drop your images into it so as to keep them separated from your source code.  Use the path relative to the resources folder that you included as a source directory in the build path options (if you weren't aware of how to add the folder as a source folder, right click on the project go to properties go to flex build path click the source tab and add it there).  In your code in the "renderer" view up above add "images/" to the beginning of the string like

rimage = "images/"+resArr2[1]+".jpg";

Let me know if I totally missed the issue or am interpreting what you wrote incorrectly.  It appears your binding as it is is just fine though.

Comment: Hello shuanhusain! Thanks for reply, but I load images from RSS description, not with image folder. I make mistake in my question. Source code from icon.mxml file (itemRenderer) is in first code box. I`m a beginner in Flex and programming :( Are you have mail, msn, etc, I will contact you :)

Comment: My e-mail and gmail are my name with a dot in the middle, but honestly I prefer StackOverflow since I can jump around and take things at my own pace on here (it's a good way to blow off steam and re-affirm that I know something when I'm neck deep in my own work).  If you'd like to chat gmail is the easiest way to have a back and forth, but again that's not on public record where other people can benefit from the dialog so I sort of prefer using this site.  If we arrive at a solution over IM it should at least get posted back here in case someone runs onto the same issues.

Comment: I'll re-review your first code block and see if I can see what's going wrong, so I'm to assume that rimage is the full absolute path to an image file then correct?